# How to find if where statement is occurred in the code

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I don't know how to find if the `where` statement occurred in the code when I execute it:

```
Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("
                           UPDATE ShTb 
                           SET Email=@EmailAddress, 
                           Temp=@temp, 
                           TEL=@telnum, 
                           TempTime=@temptime 
                           WHERE ShID=@SharjID", con1)

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", EmailAddress)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SharjID", SharjID)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temp", temp)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telnum", telnum)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temptime", temptime)

con1.Open()
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
con1.Close()
```

Comment: what do you mean by `"where statement" is ocured `?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: I mean I want to show a message on a label when `ShID=@SharjID`  is not true.

Comment: you are not comparing `ShID=@SharjID` then how do you think it will return true?
you are updating your table with 4 columns where `ShID=@SharjID`

Comment: I compared it but i did not type it here.

Comment: @user3724490 then show your code where you compared

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to know if any rows were effected by the update.
You can do this by checking the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
Dim rowsEffected = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
if rowsEffected > 0 Then
  'One or more rows were changed
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by the command.

For `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. (MSDN)

```
dim r1 as int

r1=cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

If r1 > 0 --one, or more rows were affected....
```